# How to access gem5 stats from the Python script?

Tags: gem5

Is it possible to run the simulation for a certain amount of ticks, and then read the value of selected statistics from the Python config script?

Answer (score 0):

Edit: a patch has been submitted at: https://gem5-review.googlesource.com/c/public/gem5/+/33176

As of 3ca404da175a66e0b958165ad75eb5f54cb5e772 it does not seem possible, but it is likely easy to implement.

We already have a loop that goes over all stats in the Python under `src/python/m5/stats/__init__.py`, so there are python stat objects fully exposed and iterated, but the actual stat value appears not exposed to them, only the stat name:

```
def _dump_to_visitor(visitor, root=None):
    # Legacy stats
    if root is None:
        for stat in stats_list:
            stat.visit(visitor)

    # New stats
    def dump_group(group):
        for stat in group.getStats():
            stat.visit(visitor)
```

The visit method then leads the value to be written out to the stat file, but the Python does not do it.

However, `visit` is already a pybind11 Python C++ extension defined at src/python/pybind11/stats.cc:

```
    py::class_<Stats::Info, std::unique_ptr<Stats::Info, py::nodelete>>(
        m, "Info")
        .def("visit", &Stats::Info::visit)
        ;
```

so you would likely need to expose the value there.

One annoyance is that each stat type that derives from `Stats::Info` has a different data representation, e.g. scalars return a `double`:

```
class ScalarInfo : public Info
{
  public:
    virtual Counter value() const = 0;
```

but vectors an `std::vector`:

```
class VectorInfo : public Info
{
  public:
    virtual const VCounter &value() const = 0;
```

and so there is no base `value()` method due to the different return types, you'd juts need to expose one per base class.

TODO I couldn't see the `value()` method on the Python still, likely because they were still objects of the base class, needs more investigating.

Answer (score 0):

You can use variation of the [gem5-stat-summarizer](https://github.com/Hanz94/gem5-stat-summarizer). gem5-stat-summarizer is used to extract selected gem5 statistics to a csv file when you have multiple stats.txt files